# If statement true but not executing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am creating an explore page for my social network. As everyone knows the explore page is where you go to find content from people you are NOT following. But I am having a problem. I see the posts of the users I am following.

I first fetch the `user_from` in the following table. Then I check if the `userLoggedIn`(me) is the `user_from` if I am I don't want to see the posts of the people I am following. If I'm not the `user_from` then I want to see any posts in the `posts` table.

But the code I have now goes straight to the else statement and doesn't run the if statement even though it is true. Can someone help me ?

```
$user_following_query = $con->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) user_from FROM following WHERE ? in 
    (user_from) AND unfollowed = "0"');
$user_following_query->bind_param("s", $userLoggedIn);
$user_following_query->execute();
$user_following_query->bind_result($user_following);    
$user_following_query_result = $user_following_query->get_result();

while ($row = $user_following_query_result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $user_following = $row['user_from'];
}


if($userLoggedIn == $user_following) {

    die("Following");
    
} else {

    die("Not Following");
}
```

Comment: that query looks wrong

Comment: Don't put 0 in quotes in the where clause. It's a number not a string.

Comment: In the column I have it saved as a string. @Grasper

Comment: have you checked if the query works at all, for example by enabling the genral log and see if ot runs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query does not ruturn a value for `user_from`. It returns a count. So the value for $user_following is null.

Comment: he aliases the count as user_from, so if the querys works which i doubt,he will get a column that has that name

Comment: Any idea on how to also check if my unfollowed column equals 1 in the if statement ? `if($userLoggedIn == $user_following && 'unfollowed == 0') {`

Comment: You should check the query. I agree with @nbk that it's probably not working as you expect and they are correct about the alias, I missed that.